# UILabel Value of type 'String' have no member 'text' (Static Custom Cell)

Tags: swift, uilabel, xcode8, tablecell

I'm getting user information from json but when I assign the values to my labels, it shows the error `(Value of type 'String' have no member 'text')`.

Is it because the Custom static table cell? How to fix it? My foundation is not good...

[image]
And:

[image]

Comment: You need to unwrap your String and it should work

Comment: Label name and constant name you declared same. Change the name and try

Comment: try to add self in front of label name. like self.empnameLabel.text

Comment: You shouldn't use same identifiers for the label as for string value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different variable names. Its good practise to have unique variable names

As the variable names are same as variable values you are getting the error

UILabel has name `empNameLabel : UILabel`(In `viewDidLoad`) and value also has same name.

change

```
let empNameLabel = user!["crew_name"] as? String //conflicting name with UILabel iboutlet
```

to

```
let empNameValue = user!["crew_name"] as? String //variable name is unique
```

Also you should not force unwrap options(`user` in your case)

it should be

```
var empNameValue = ""
if let unwrappedUser = user {
    if let empNameValue = unwrappedUser["crew_name"] as? String {
        empNameLabel.text = empNameValue //assign value to UILabel
    }
}
```

Comment: Simpler version:
if let empNameValue = user?["crew_name"] as? String {
    empNameLabel.text = empNameValue
}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get ".text" value from "String" which is not possible. 
Either use self:

```
self.empnameLabel.text = empnameLabel
```

or give different names to string constant:

```
self.empnameLabel.text = str
```

or directly store that value to lable:

```
self.empnameLabel.text = user[crewname]! as! String
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you give the outlet and variable the same name.

The variable empNameLabel has no property called text.

text is the property of empNameLabel outlet.
change the variable name. Eg
let empName = user!["crew_name"] as? String

Answer (score 0):

- Change your label variable name
- Set your newLabelVariable.text to the empNameLabel